# node js monk update lingers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I'm new to node.js, mongoDB, monk and express (All on the latest versions). and as I'm working I encountered the next situation:

I have a table that is updated, and I read from it periodically. When I read from it, I update a flag in the database, to prevent rereading. (I don't want to delete it in case I need to check up things).

Now the problem is that after I use the update in monk, it exists forever. Every post I add after gets flagged, I have to restart the server for it to go back to normal. And when I read, the problem reoccurs.

I managed to solve it by adding req.pause() in the code - but I'm uncomfortable with this, as I don't want to have a bunch of live requests bogging down the server.

Here is my code :

```
  function(req,res){
    this.getNotifications = function(req,res){
      var username = req.params.username;
      var justOpened = req.params.justOpened;

    var callback = function(e,doc) {
      if(doc != ""){
        db.update(username + "Notifications",{read:0},{$set:{read:1}},function(){});
        req.pause(); // if I delete this the update keeps going
        res.json(doc);
        res.status = 200;
        res.end();
      } else {
        setTimeout(function(){db.find(username + "Notifications",read:0},{},callback);},5000);
      }
    };

    if (justOpened == "true"){
      db.find(username + "Notifications",{},{},callback);       
    } else {
      db.find(username + "Notifications",{read : 0},{},callback);   
    }
 }
```

and my database.update method looks like this :

```
this.update = function(collectionName,queryObj,update,callback){
    var collection = db.get(collectionName);
    collection.update(queryObj,update,{multi:true},callback);
}
```

Basically if I remove the req.pause line, the update never ends, and works into the future.

Does anyone know what causes these?

Comment: You may have incorrectly set up your update object by missing a colon `:`  in this line `db.update(username + "Notifications",{read:0},{$set{read:1}},function(){});`. Try changing it to `db.update(username + "Notifications",{read:0},{$set: {read:1}},function(){});`

Comment: Thanks for noticing this, but actually, it's ok in my code, I accidentally deleted it when I was formatting my code. I do hope it's something as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the question. And I'm adding it here in case anyone ever has the same problem.

adding a return to the code stopped the function.